# Rails: controller that lets teacher only see posts his students make

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have a teacher controller that lets the teacher see all student posts.

```
def index
  if params[:user_id]
    @posts = Post.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
  else
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

How would you let teachers see posts of their students only, and not posts made by students who have  a different teacher? I am using devise.

This is what I have for the teacher controller:

```
class TeachersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


def index
  if params[:user_id]
   @posts = Post.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
 else
    @posts = Post.all
  end

end

end
```

Comment: You should provide more info about `teachers` models, authentication gems e.t.c.

Comment: The better you prepare your question, the better answers you get. check what is relevant for the problem and what not. Is "Posts" really the only model in your system relevant for this problem? Don't forget that most readers live in another country than you.

Answer (score 1):

Without having any information about your associations or authentication, I'll answer by making the following assumptions:

1. A post belongs_to a student, a student has_many posts
2. A student belongs_to a teacher, a teacher has_many students
3. The teacher is the current user

The most simple way to limit posts to a teacher is by defining an additional ActiveRecord association. In the Teacher class, you might add:

```
has_many :student_posts, through: :students, source: :posts
```

In your controller, you can do something like:

```
class TeacherController

  before_action :find_teacher, only: [:index]

  def index
    @posts = @teacher.student_posts
  end

  private

  def find_teacher
    @teacher = current_user
  end 
end
```

ActiveRecord will only return posts that belong to students that belong to a given teacher. Note that this is a concept illustration and not meant to by copy and pasted.

Comment: When doing so I receive an undefined method for "find_teacher". Sorry, I'm a real noob at this. I notice these errors a lot. Can someone explain?

Comment: I suggest reading up on Rails. Here a link to controller documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html